# how to integrate grpc service with graphql?

Tags: graphql, grpc

I have a grpc service that contains several apis(getName, getInfo, etc), and a grpc endpoint, something like this,

```
configuration-dev-grpc.kmc-default.us-west-2**.com:443
```

I create a graphql project, how can I connect the graplql with grpc service through that endpoint, or I need to do it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC and GraphQL are often considered alternatives but, if we consider gRPC as just procedure calls, there's no reason why a GraphQL server could not be implemented against a gRPC client to serve GraphQL clients.

At least one group has a solution:

https://github.com/ysugimoto/grpc-graphql-gateway

If you control the gRPC server, it would possibly be preferable to implement the GraphQL server alongside it, i.e. directly against whatever API it provides. Doing this would avoid the networking between gRPC client and server and the Protobuf (un)marshaling.